# Fetch just some values in database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print only the booktitle and publisher without similar booktitle from my other table.

```
while($row_result_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
            $fetched1 = $row_result_kinder1_comp_lit[3]; //fetch booktitle column from       $sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit //
            echo $fetched1;
        }
            while($row_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
            $fetched2 = $row_kinder1_comp_lit[1]; //fetch booktitle column column from       $sql_kinder1_comp_lit //
        if($fetched1 != $fetched2) {
     echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['booktitle'];
     echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['publisher'];
    }
}
```

the problem is the $fetched1 inside if statement only get the value of the last row in my database. So it hide only the book in the $sql_kinder1_comp_lit with the same booktitle in the last row of my $result_sql_kinder1_comp_lit;

```
my table $sql_kinder1_comp_lit is
id    booktitle    publisher
1     book1        publisher1
2     book2        publisher2
3     book3        publisher3

my table $sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit is
id    booktitle    publisher
1     book1        publisher1
2     book2        publisher2
```

I want to display only the book3 because it doesnt have the same booktitle from the other table.

Comment: Why not just fetch the items you need in the SQL query? Also, we don't know any information about your tables in your database.

Comment: Could you move the } so your second while is in the first one? Then again could be better for performance to save values in a array so you could search that array in the second while.

Comment: @spencer, I did this for purpose, I don't want to display the booktitle and publisher of the row with the same booktitle to other table. Sorry I don't know how to become more specific about my problem. Please see the edit.

Comment: @daniel, sorry my knowledge in php and mysql is not that good. Can I have example? I tried moving my second while to the first one then it only fetch the first row in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attached an example of how you could do it with an array that saves what book titles you've seen and not displaying the ones already present in the first set of books.

The if statement checks if there is a value inside of the array so the use of a boolean for the array isn't required but I feel it's a bit more descriptive.

```
<?php
    var $bookarray;
    while($row_result_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
        $first_booktitle = $row_result_kinder1_comp_lit[3]; //fetch booktitle column from       $sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit //
        $bookarray[$first_booktitle] = true;
    }

    while($row_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
        $second_booktitle = $row_kinder1_comp_lit[1]; //fetch booktitle column column from       $sql_kinder1_comp_lit //
        if(!$bookarray[$second_booktitle]) {
            echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['booktitle'];
            echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['publisher'];
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! This really solve my problem. I'm sorry because I can't upvote you now. Thank you so much!!!! I just remove the var.

Comment: Been a while since I wrote PHP but the old scripting ways is hard to forget. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

It only does the last item because you are going though all the items from the first result before you start comparing. `mysqli_fetch_array` in the first while loop will keep going and at the end `$fetched1` will be the last row the query result. All of this happens before you start looking at the next query. Just move the `}` so it does not close the loop and fetches `$fetched1` to be compared with all items from `$fetched2`:

```
while($row_result_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
    $fetched1 = $row_result_kinder1_comp_lit[3]; //fetch booktitle column from       $sql_result_kinder1_comp_lit //
    echo $fetched1;

    while($row_kinder1_comp_lit = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_kinder1_comp_lit)) {
    $fetched2 = $row_kinder1_comp_lit[1]; //fetch booktitle column column from       $sql_kinder1_comp_lit //
        if($fetched1 != $fetched2) {
             echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['booktitle'];
             echo $row_kinder1_comp_lit['publisher'];
        }
    } 
}
```